# SharedPrefs to store a Time

Tags: android, time, sharedpreferences

What is the best way to store a Time in SharedPrefs. Would it be best to convert it to an int or string as the time needs to be converted back into a time after it has been retrieved from the SharedPrefs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Save:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putLong("time", Date.getTime());
editor.commit();
```

To Retrieve:

```
Date myDate = new Date(prefs.getLong("time", 0));
```